# how to show spine in uipageviewcontroller?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am creating a simple UIPageViewController with just two pages, how do I show the spine? Currently there is nothing in the middle. Also the outside borders are missing.

This is the code for UIPageViewController

```
//
//  PageViewController.m
//  pageuiviewproject
//
//

#import "PageViewController.h"
#import "contentViewController.h"
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

@interface PageViewController ()
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIPageViewController *pageViewController;
@end

@implementation PageViewController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.pageViewController = [[UIPageViewController alloc] initWithTransitionStyle:UIPageViewControllerTransitionStylePageCurl navigationOrientation:UIPageViewControllerNavigationOrientationHorizontal options:nil];

    self.pageViewController.delegate = self;
    self.pageViewController.dataSource = self;

    NSArray *viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObject:[[contentViewController alloc]init]];
    [self.pageViewController setViewControllers:viewControllers direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward animated:YES completion:nil];
    [self addChildViewController:self.pageViewController];
    [self.view addSubview:self.pageViewController.view];
    [self.pageViewController didMoveToParentViewController:self];

    self.pageViewController.view.layer.borderColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
    self.pageViewController.view.layer.borderWidth = 3.0f;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark - UIPageViewController delegate methods

-(UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController viewControllerAfterViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController{
        return [[contentViewController alloc] init];
}

-(UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController viewControllerBeforeViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController{
        return [[contentViewController alloc] init];
}

-(UIPageViewControllerSpineLocation)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController spineLocationForInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)orientation{
    NSArray *viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[[contentViewController alloc] init], [[contentViewController alloc] init], nil];
    [self.pageViewController setViewControllers:viewControllers direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward animated:YES completion:NULL];

    self.pageViewController.doubleSided = YES;
    return UIPageViewControllerSpineLocationMid;
}

@end
```

The contentViewController is currently empty. This is what it looks like in simulator ...[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j7CGB.png)

I want to create the following look [mosaic app look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/55O7H.png). Is this a custom look? I was hoping this would be possible by setting UIPageViewController properties.

Comment: Well you hoped wrong. :( UIPageViewController does not provide any "look" at all. It's just a way of showing successive view controller's views. What you put in those views, or what you show behind/around the page view controller's view, is up to you.

Comment: Thank you @matt. So to get a look and feel like Mosaic image, I need to put a book frame UIImageView of some sort and place the UIPageViewController inside the uiImageView. Still don't know how to show the spine. Is that also custom?

Comment: Yes. But you could probably just put some drawing in front of the page controller (something without user interaction, so that clicks go through to the page view controller and its views). I haven't tried it but I can't see why it wouldn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UIPageViewController does not provide any "look" at all. It's just a way of showing successive view controller's views. What you put in those views, or what you show behind/around/in front of the page view controller's view, is up to you. You want a book, draw a book.

Comment: Any ideas how do this?